# Loop to select specific numbers from a given list

Tags: python, loops

My problem is that in python i have a list of 1000 numbers. I want to select first 20 and store in "A" (another list) and next 30 in "B"(another list), again next 20 in "A", next 30 in "B" untill the list ends. How to do that? Can anyone help please?

Comment: `store in "A"` ... what is `A` ?

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen... it is another list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use two nested list comprehension for this:

```
nums = list(range(2000))
A = [x for i in range( 0, len(nums), 50) for x in nums[i:i+20]]
B = [x for i in range(20, len(nums), 50) for x in nums[i:i+30]]
```

That means (for `A`): Starting at index 0, 50, 100 etc., take the next 20 elements and add them to `A`. Analogous for `B`. You might also use `itertools.islice` for the `nums[i:i+n]` part to avoid creating a bunch of temporary sub-lists.

Of course, this assumes that `A` and `B` do not already exist. If they do, and you want to add elements to them, use a regular loop and `extend` (not tested):

```
for i in range(0, len(nums), 50):
    A.extend(nums[i   :i+20])
    B.extend(nums[i+20:i+50])
```

You do not have to check the indices again within the loop; if `i+20` is already bigger than the last index in the list, `B` will just get extended with the empty list in the last step.

Answer (score 2):

I made a function that can do what you're asking

```py
def split_list(lst, gap1, gap2):
    tmp = lst.copy()
    out1, out2 = [], []
    while tmp:
        out1.extend(tmp[:gap1])
        tmp = tmp[gap1:]
        
        out2.extend(tmp[:gap2])
        tmp = tmp[gap2:]
    return out1, out2
```

`gap1` and `gap2` are the length of each subset you want to store, so in your case `gap1=20` and `gap2=30`.

Example

```py
numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]
A, B = split_list(numbers, 2, 3)

print(A)
print(B)
```

Answer (score 2):

Let's first define the followings:

```
A = [] #empty list
B = [] #empty list
```

And let's call your first list (that includes 1000 numbers), as `my_list`.

Then, a simple solution can be as following:

```
counter = 0
c_a = 2
c_b = 3
while (counter < len(my_list)):
    A = A + my_list[counter:counter+c_a]
    B = B + my_list[counter+c_a : counter + c_a + c_b]
    counter = counter + c_a + c_b
```

Answer (score 2):

I suggest generating a 2D nested list, which contains sublists each having 20 elements in it.  Here is a one line way of doing that with a list comprehension:

```py
x = range(1, 1001)
output = [x[idx*20:(idx*20 + 20)] for idx in range(0, len(x) / 20)]
```

Here is a version which operates on a smaller set of data, for demonstration purposes:

```py
x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
output = [x[idx*3:(idx*3 + 3)] for idx in range(0, len(x) / 3)]
print(output)  # [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```

Comment: Why not `range` with `step` instead of `idx*X`? In particular, this may raise a TypeError if the list is not evenly divisible by 20 or 3.

Comment: @tobias_k I'm a newbie to Python (despite being like 5 votes away from a gold medal in that tag).  You are free to edit my question if you wish.